# Negative consumer externality vs demerit good - what's the difference?

Tags: microeconomics, consumer-theory, externalities

The example I was given for each was cigarettes.

1. What market may have negative consumer externalities but is not a market for a demerit good?
2. What is a type of demerit good that may not have a negative consumer externality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Demerit goods are goods where it is agreed by society that consumption is **harmful for the consumer** yet it is still consumed due to bounded rationality or because you disagree with society while negative consumer externalities occur when actions of a consumer is **harmful for society**.

**Goods that are demerit but may not have negative consumer externality:**

Any type of unhealthy food. E.g. cinnabuns.

Carcinogenic stuff, alcohol, etc.

Basically anything you regret having consumed a few hours later.

If consumption of these goods do not harm society, then there are no negative externalities, as long as no one else cares about the consumer :'(

**Good that may have negative consumer externality but may not be a demerit good:**

Loud music

Comment: Thanks denesp. What about goods whose markets may have negative consumer externalities but aren't demerit goods?

Comment: I'm gonna edit your answer and see how community responds. Thanks! ^-^